# how to read pickle file python by C++

Tags: python, c++, apache-kafka, pickle

My work is image processing
i use kafka to send/receive image

when kafka producer send image must be encode. After used pickle.dump to send data

```
frame = cv2.imencode('.JPEG', frame)
pickle.dump( frame,datasend)
```

then kafka consumer receved image (writed by c++) is pickle format.

so How can i to decode

```
img = cv2.imdecode(dataRecevice, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

i was try install picking tool http://www.picklingtools.com/ on ubuntu 18.04
but can't (i try and serching can't fix error when build)

Someone help me different way read pickle format (c++)
or link guide build Pickling tool

thank you

Comment: For the pickling tools build, remove the space between the `load` and the `:` at line 61 of the makefile It's new behavior introduced by make 4. It's literally trying to load a shared object called `:`

Comment: @Petesh do you know about convert data received from kafka  (Buffer) to Array<char> (in Pickling tools